# programmatically change browser settings to do not cache document

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any possibility to block browser to cache pages in javascript ? Because when user logs in then by pressing history button it returns to form although PHP has implemented redirection if user is logged in. But the browser caches the page and let the user to visit login page again.

Comment: No you cannot change the browser's settings. But you can properly declare your page cache preferences: [How to expire webpage when back/forward from browser button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360033/how-to-expire-webpage-when-back-forward-from-browser-button)

Answer (score 1):

try this meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running it on a server, you could run a [phantom querystring](http://davidwalsh.name/prevent-cache). It's not very well explained on the site, however, the idea of this is in order to stop caching by having constantly changing links.

Comment: Please include the gist of the answer here, link-only answers may go stale and become useless.

Comment: @deceze, thanks for the input, I'll edit it and keep it in mind!